# Error: Expected specifier-qualifier-list before XXX

Tags: ios, xcode4

it did it so many times and i didn't had any problems with it, but this time i still getting the error above, my relevant code is this:

```
#import "PiecesChoisies.h"

@interface SelectionMobilier : UIViewController {
IBOutlet PiecesChoisies *piecesChoisies;//Error: Expected specifier-qualifier-list before PiecesChoisies 
}
@end
```

Thanx in advance for any suggestions :)

**EDIT :**
I try this :

```
#import "PiecesChoisies.h"

    @interface SelectionMobilier : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet NSString *piecesChoisies;//Error: Expected specifier-qualifier-list before PiecesChoisies 
    }
    @end
```

Now i got this stack:

[image]

Comment: yes but you need to comment out the import statement as well. Sorry I should have made that clear.

Answer (score 2):

`PiecesChoisies` is not recognized as a type. This may happen because it has cyclical dependencies.

The following code example illustrates the problem. Classes A and B create a circular dependency trying to import each other.

```
#import "B.h"               // <-- A imports B
@interface A : NSObject
@end

#import "A.h"
@implementation A
@end


#import "A.h"              // <-- and B imports A
@interface B : NSObject
@end

#import "B.h"
@implementation B
@end
```

Because the classes are never created, the compiler treats them as unknown tokens, so the error shows as `Expected specifier-qualifier-list before XXX`. In other words "I expected something meaningful before XXX".

To remove the circular dependency:

1. And add a forward class declaration (`@class`) on the interface file.
2. Move the `#import` from the interface to the implementation file.

The class declaration tells the compiler "don't worry, I'll define this later", so the header becomes safe to import because the conflicting definition is now out of sight on the implementation file.

Here is the result for the previous example:

```
@class B;             // <---- #import "B.h" replaced with @class B
@interface A : NSObject
@end

#import "A.h"
#import "B.h"         // <---- #import "B.h" added
@implementation A
@end
```

And do the same with class B:

```
@class A;             // <---- #import "A.h" replaced with @class A
@interface B : NSObject
@end

#import "B.h"
#import "A.h"         // <---- #import "A.h" added
@implementation B
@end
```

Comment: Yes, actually `PiecesChoisies` import `SelectionMobilier ` and `SelectionMobilier ` does import `PiecesChoisies`, how can i fix that?

Comment: Move the import PiecesChoisies to your .m, and add this in your .h: @class PiecesChoisies; You can read more about this searching stackoverflow for: forward class declaration [objective-c]

Comment: I added an example. That screenshot helps, maybe you forgot to do the same in the other class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be located in PiecesChoisies.h. Change:

```
 IBOutlet PiecesChoisies *piecesChoisies;
```

to

```
 IBOutlet NSString *piecesChoisies;
```

that will confirm that the problem is located in the .h file.

Comment: But `piecesChoisies` is a `UIViewController` and not `NSString`

Comment: yes. This is just a quick test to confirm that the problem is located in PiecesChoisies.h

Comment: I have edited my post, please help me figure out what dealing with :)

Comment: comment out the import and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a header file, use

```
@class PiecesChoisies;
```

Instead of the import statement. Import the .h file in your .m file.