# Compile errors: can't find protocol declaration

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to learn Objective-C from a book, and ran into the following errors while trying to work through an exercise in Xcode (arrow indicates place of issue).

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FlashCard.h"
#import "CreateCardViewController.h"

--> @interface FlashCardsViewController : UIViewController <CreateCardDelegate> {
```

The above code results in the error: "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CreateCardDelegate'. But I am importing "CreateCardViewController.h" where I have declared: 
    @property (nonatomic, assign) id cardDelegate;
so don't know what the issue is...

Having browsed a few post I suspect it may it be due to a circular #import dependency? but if that is the case then I'm not sure how to rectify this error. If you have any suggestions then please explain and do keep in mind that I am new to objective-c.

Comment: can you please post more code, so that I can explain? Please show the implementation of CreateCardViewController.h

Comment: Do you have @protocole CreateCardDelegate in CreateCardViewController.h?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about circular dependencies, but if you want to know how to avoid them in the future read http://stackoverflow.com/a/7428777/412916

Answer (score 2):

You are not defining correctly

```
@protocol CreateCardDelegate
  ....
@end
```

in your `CreateCardViewController.h` file. Please review that definition and post the relevant code for more help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the CreateCardDelegate protocol somewhere.  Here's an example of a protocol declaration (in a .h file).

```
@protocol MyClassDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)myClass:(MyClass *)myClass someEventOccured:(NSInteger)value;
- (void)myClass:(MyClass *)myClass someOtherEventOccured:(NSInteger)value;

@end
```

In your case you need to have a `@protocol CreateCardDelegate` somewhere in those header files and import it into your .m file. Do you?